# WCF - Pass inherited class object

Tags: c#, wcf, wshttpbinding

I have a data contract in which i specify a property of type Stream, now if i want to pass a child type MemoryStream it throws an error, as SOAP message doesn't know anything about MemoryStream.

I tried to put the attribute (knowntype) on the property, but it is only allowed on the declaration of the class.
So should i put it while declaring the class or something else needs to be done

That works, putting known type while declaring class. The problem was MemoryStream is successfully passed but not FileStream. I am using wsHttpBinding so cant use transfer mode as stream. Can anyone please help why is it so?

Comment: What error exactly is it throwing?

Comment: Type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' with data contract name 'MemoryStream:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

Comment: It works after i put a known type attribute, but another problem i am facing is, FileStream if passed gives null object, MemoryStream works fine. Any reason for it

Comment: Maybe this is forbidden due to security reason. Could you transform FileStream into byte[]?